# LockablePivot throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to implement the lockablePivot control found in the Windows Phone Toolkit - August 2011 (7.1 SDK) release.

When I add an itemtemplate to the control every time i change the isLocked property during runtime it throws a InvalidCastException. Are there any workarounds to this?

Need help. Thanks

---

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <toolkit:LockablePivot Name="Pages" SelectionChanged="Pivot_Changed" ItemsSource="{Binding}">           

        <toolkit:LockablePivot.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <Button Content="Lock" Click="Button_Click"/>

                    <Image Stretch="Uniform" local:WP7ImageZoomer.IsZoomingEnabled="True" ManipulationStarted="Image_ManipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="Image_ManipulationCompleted" ManipulationDelta="Image_ManipulationDelta" CacheMode="BitmapCache">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <BitmapImage x:Name="Bit" UriSource="{Binding Img}" DownloadProgress="BitmapImage_DownloadProgress" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation"/>
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>
                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </toolkit:LockablePivot.ItemTemplate>
    </toolkit:LockablePivot>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
private void Image_ManipulationStarted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationStartedEventArgs e)
    {

        this.Pages.IsLocked = true;// Throws InvalidCastException here
    }

    private void Image_ManipulationCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Pages.IsLocked = false;
    }

    private void Image_ManipulationDelta(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ManipulationDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        //this.Pages.IsLocked = true;
    }
```

Comment: please show your code. Don't just describe it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

There is an open ticket for that bug. See http://silverlight.codeplex.com/workitem/10793. Please don't forget to vote.